# Dynamically Copy/Create the Full Structure of an Asp.NET Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, gridview, dynamic

Ok so I have a GridView created on my .aspx page and it has the exact structure I want. How make copies of it in the code-behind? Copies with the exact same structure of TemplateFields and ItemTemplates?

If copying is not possible, how can I reproduce the GridView in the code-behind? Add the TemplateFields, ItemTemplates, etc.

Why am I doing it this way? I need a separate, identical GridView for each column of a database. I've been looking around and only found one resource for making the grid dynamically (see the resource below). Given my time constraints, I'd like to simply copy the one I already have.

Resource: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/624380-gridview-generated-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) with the gridview.  This will allow you to create several instances of that structure.  If it is created programatically you may be better off creating a [Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386416.aspx) that will allow you better control on the page.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll give it a try. :)